# SOAP Web service completing before all data is processed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, enterprise-library

I have a SOAP web-service I am testing locally in my development environment. I have a test Winforms application that consumes this web-service on localhost.

When the web-service is called it is meant to read from a table in a MSSQL 2008 DB and return a dataset (this part is working).

My Winforms application iterates through the rows of the dataset and inserts the dataset's rows into the local DB. Basically, I am copying data from one table on one database to another database's table (1:1) via web-service.

### The problem..

..is that I am getting X thousand rows via the web-service and when I iterate through them on my Winforms application the code just stops looping at around 200-300 rows. I have stuck a breakpoint and using Visual Studio's 'Immediate Window' I have verified that there are X thousand rows with data against them.

The project is an old .NET 2.0 Web site, it uses an old version of the Microsoft Enterprise Library v2.0.50727 for data-access.

Here is the problematic code on the Winforms application:

```
public static int PopulateLocalTable(DataSet ds, string DBInstance, string DBServer)
{
    if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}; Integrated Security=True;", DBInstance, DBServer)))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.myStoredProc", conn))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Added for debugging purposes.
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
                    int teamid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TeamID"]);
                    int companyid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CompanyID"]);
                    string team_name = Convert.ToString(dr["Team_Name"]);
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"]);
                    string aaa = Convert.ToString(dr["aaa"]);
                    int bbb = Convert.ToInt32(dr["bbb"]);
                    decimal ccc = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["ccc"]);
                    DateTime ddd = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ddd"]);

                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", id));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TeamID", teamid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", companyid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Team_Name", team_name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", date));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aaa", aaa));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bbb", bbb));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ccc", ccc));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ddd", ddd));

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config settings on the Winforms application:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:11288/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap" name="Service1Soap"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

If I have tried modifying the connection/command timeout and I can not get it working. It is like the connection is timing out or the stream is being restricted. I am hoping it is just a config setting.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you have the `command` creation outside the loop so you end up adding more and more parameters.

Create a new `command` object inside the loop.

You can use the `using` statement to ensure that connections and commands are cleaned up:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // do stuf
    }
}
```

**Update**:  I noticed now that the parameters are cleared.  Try creating the command in the loop anyway :)

Comment: ugh, it actually turned out that I had a logic issue in the stored proc being called. I marked this as the answer as it uses the Using statement which handles SQL connections/commands in a safer way from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Check the BufferResponse property of the web method. The default value is TRUE (the response is buffered), but for large amount of data, buffering is not suggested: try set it to FALSE.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.bufferresponse.aspx).